# Duda cookies de «entrada del usuario»

Tags: cookies

Estoy ayudando a unos compañeros de una asociación de danza a hacer una web en la que la gente pueda apuntarse a las actividades que se organizan.

Es muy básica, simplemente un formulario y cuando se le da al botón de "submit" se guardan los datos (incluye las capas que pide la RGPD).

El problema viene porque muchos usuarios, con las prisas y los dedos gordos en el móvil, meten mal los datos (sobre todo el email). Para reducir estos fallos, mi idea era guardar los datos (cifrados) en una cookie de modo que la siguiente vez que se inscriban, sólo tengan que revisar los datos. Además, para ellos sería mucho más cómodo.

El problema es que nuestra web, al ser sencilla, no usaba cookies por lo que tampoco mostraba el aviso famoso. Mi duda es, ¿si incluyo esta cookie debería añadir el aviso? Por lo que veo en el enlace de abajo, las cookies de «entrada del usuario», que incluyen los datos introducidos en formularios, están exceptuadas... pero no estoy seguro de si abarcan el caso que comento :-(

http://www.interior.gob.es/documents/10180/13073/Guia_Cookies.pdf

Comment: ¿Qué código tienes? ¿En qué lenguaje trabajas? Faltan esos detalles para que tu pregunta esté completa

Answer (score 0):

@anythingg está hecho en php, el código que uso para guardar los datos es es el siguiente:

```
function save_datos_to_cookie($yourName,$yourEmail,$yourPhone,$your_dni){
$cookie_name = "datos";

$json_object->nombre = $yourName;
$json_object->email  = $yourEmail;
$json_object->telefono = $yourPhone;
$json_object->dni    = $your_dni;

//Convierte los datos a un único string
$myJSON = json_encode($json_object);

//Encripta los datos antes de guardarlos
$myJSON_encrypted = openssl_encrypt ( $myJSON, 'AES-128-ECB', 'passphrase');
$cookie_value = $myJSON_encrypted;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 90), "/");
}
```